# Is this Possible to add Keyboard Predictive option in UISearchBar keyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard, uisearchbar

Is this Possible to add Keyboard Predictive option in UISearchBar keyboard. 
OR apple have any guidline for this. Please help me.

Comment: In the attributes inspector go to correction attribute and make it YES

Answer (score 1):

keyboard properties will be same in all textfields. but you can customise it as per your needs. you can enable autocorrection and prediction in it[image: Please see this image to reffer]

Comment: click on search bar and see right side properties bar. properties are still same. i did practical of this. you can try it. on my side its working fine. predictions are showing.